# Is there a simple way to make perforce 'automatically' ensure that two files, under different paths, always contain the same contents?

Tags: perforce

We currently have a header file that sits in two different depots (identical copies), and whenever we update it, we have to manually make sure that the other copy is updated as well.

Is there a simple way to get perforce to enforce this? Or would I need to set up something with triggers? (I'm a bit worried about doing it 'properly' if so, don't have any experience with that).

I assume you'd need admin access to the perforce server to do this?

Comment: I'd think this would be easy to do. Yes, you'd need admin access to set up the trigger. The trigger would be a change-commit trigger pointing to the path of the file you always want copied. You'll then have it run a script that would perform the copy. To see what you'd include in the script, just look at the output from p4v (if you are currently copying it that way) and use those commands to create your script.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a trigger, you'd want to put a change-commit trigger on the file:

```
Triggers:
    copy-always change-commit //depot/my/file.h "my-copy-script"
```

and then `my-copy-script` would run commands like:

```
p4 copy //depot/my/file.h //depot/my/other/file.h
p4 submit -d "copy my file to my other file"
```

But!  Keeping two identical copies is an antipattern and you shouldn't do it.  Keep one file and use client mappings, branch mappings, streams, or symlinks to make it look like it's in two places.  The exact solution you use depends on why you think you need two copies of this file in the first place.  :)

Comment: We have an internal library we don't want to expose to customers, but various definitions/declarations we also want to include in our public headers.

The 'obvious' solution is to extract out a third library that both depend on, but we already had enough problems after creating the first (as it's shared within the company, while our team works on just a single product), that we wanted to avoid that

Comment: Also, sometimes one version gets updated, and sometimes the other.

I'm guessing it would be bad to set up two triggers that are opposites of the other? Would that cause infinite recursion, or race conditions?

Comment: You could definitely have race conditions there, yeah.  One reason that trying to do this at all is a bad idea; a single depot file has a bunch of very desirable (in this case) atomicity semantics that you're giving up without any particularly good reason by trying to turn it into two copies.

Comment: Creating a third library isn't necessary; you just want a single depot file to appear in multiple contexts.  With streams this would likely be a very simple `import+` declaration.  How do your public headers get distributed?  Could you just have a manifest that grabs a defined set of files from the internal library and adds them to the headers?  Perforce's client API distribution works this way; there's a Jamfile that defines which files within the library implementation are "public" and those files just get added to the tarball.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, I guess. I think there's some reason we can't use streams at work, something would need to be upgraded or something.

Comment: You can also do this with classic client views if you need them in different places in different workspaces.  Impossible to tell you how exactly to put the files where you need them if I don't know where you need them, but there's a very wide array of solutions for this kind of thing.  :)  Classic clients also offer &-mappings which let you have the same file in multiple places in a single workspace!

Comment: @Bwmat IMO you should have a single, canonical location for the file in the repository, and make your build system make a copy as necessary.